# in fact it doesn't insert vales into table but wrote that did

Tags: mysql, database

Please, help me to understand what is the problem

I have table order

```
 CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `Order_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ordered_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `Payment_method_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Ship_Type_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Customer_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Expecting',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_id`),
  KEY `ORDERS_fk0` (`Payment_method_id`),
  KEY `ORDERS_fk1` (`Ship_Type_id`),
  KEY `ORDERS_fk2` (`Customer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ORDERS_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`Payment_method_id`) REFERENCES `payment_methods` (`Payment_Method_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ORDERS_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`Ship_Type_id`) REFERENCES `ship_types` (`Ship_Type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ORDERS_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`Customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

also I have

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_methods` (
  `Payment_Method_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Payment_Type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Payment_Method_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I try to run this code

```
insert into orders  VALUES
(
orders.Order_id= 111,
orders.Ordered_Date='2012-05-01',
orders.Payment_method_id=(select payment_methods.Payment_Method_id from payment_methods where payment_methods.Payment_Type='Cash'),
orders.Ship_Type_id=(select ship_types.Ship_Type_id from ship_types where ship_types.Ship_Type='Pickup from issuing point'),
orders.Customer_id=(select customers.Customer_id from customers where customers.login='maria'),
orders.Status='asf'
);
```

It insert row, but when I look  at the table order I see that it created raw where all fields are 0.

What it can be?

Comment: I have my doubts that `VALUES` list in your [`INSERT INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) in any way valid. Are you getting errors?

Comment: right now I got Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' but earlier I didn't have this

Comment: As a note, using `INT(5)` is asking for trouble here. That's only 5 places, or `99999` entries maximum. Just use `INT` with no restrictions unless you have a compelling reason.